# Existing force.com project invalid login

Tags: login, login-errors, invalid

I don't know what happened ?

I use these project daily and now I'm unable to:

- Synchronize with Server
- Refresh from Server

When I try. I get an Invalid Login message:
[image]

The login credentials haven't changed. In fact nothing has changed on my side!?
If I create a new force.com project. It works just fine!

I tried closing/reopening the project/eclipse/computer nothing worked !!!

Is there an eclipse config file that I can delete that will force its regeneration or any ideas to resolve this problem ?

Comment: If you re-type your login credentials again, are you getting the same error ?

Comment: Well, just re-typing the credential did nothing. I just entered a false password and click apply. And then I've put back the good password and I got my project back in business!!! I just posted what I did as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I resolved the problem!!!

Here's what I've done:

1. Put a wrong password in the Eclipse force.com project
2. Apply
3. Put back the good password
4. Apply

Et voilà!

I'm able to work again!!!
I just had to add back some metadata components to the project.

Hope it'll help someone with the same problem.